# can you explain this code I found as a solution to an edabit problem?

Tags: python

I found this solution on a problem on edabit, but I cant get my head around it.

```
def count_overlapping(intervals, point):
    return sum(min(x)<=point<=max(x) for x in intervals)
```

This is the problem text

> Create a function that takes in a list of intervals and returns how
> many intervals overlap with a given point.
>
> An interval overlaps a particular point if the point exists inside the
> interval, or on the interval's boundary. For example the point 3
> overlaps with the interval [2, 4] (it is inside) and [2, 3] (it is on
> the boundary).

Comment: Please update your question with a specific part you are having trouble with. Also, please check the syntax. I'm sure there is a missing bracket somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really the right place to ask this, but I'll answer it anyway.

```
def count_overlapping(intervals, point):
    return sum(min(x)<=point<=max(x) for x in intervals)
```

Let's pull it apart. What it does is:

```
lst = [min(x)<=point<=max(x) for x in intervals]
return sum(lst)
```

Which you can rewrite like:

```
lst = []
for x in intervals:
    if min(x) <= point <= max(x):
        lst.append(True)
    else:
        lst.append(False)
return sum(lst)
```

The reason this works is because `True` counts as a `1` and `False` counts as a `0`.